# Why does MySQL allow duplicate index names, but not duplicate foreign key names?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I can of course accommodate the requirement that foreign key names must be unique across all tables, but I've always wondered why the same requirement doesn't apply to index names?

Is there a good reason?

Comment: Why have the complication?  About the only action that needs the name is `DROP INDEX`, which needs the database name (usually implicit) and the table name.

Comment: @RickJames What's different from foreign key names then?

Comment: Well, maybe an SQL standard?  Very likely they were implemented by two different people at different times.

Comment: That's not what I'd call a good reason then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider the issue - an index or key on any table is unique to that table. So it can be implemented as only related to that particular table.**

But a foreign-key is a relation among tables, so it must be a name unique within the schema. Or at least the schema level is a suitable logical grouping.

** [ Some databases (e.g. DB2, SqlServer?) won't let you have the same index name for multiple tables within a schema, though I wonder why. Maybe it was just simple to organize it at one level instead of schema/table]